# D3 updating data on parent element wont reflect on child elements

Tags: d3.js

Let's consider I need to have a bunch of circles wrapped in `<g>` elements and I've bound my data to this parents.(`initialNodes`)

when I press the update button, the `update` function takes in the new data (`newNodes`) and I expect the x/y positions of circles to get updated, but as you can see in console, despite the fact that `d.x`/`d.y` is correctly printed, it's not taken into account in `return d.x` and therefore just `Enter` group is added to canvas.

What am I doing wrong? How can I reflect the updated data on parent `<g>`, on child elements?

```js
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

var initialNodes = [
    {"id": 0, "x": 50,  "y": 50},
    {"id": 1, "x": 100, "y": 100},
];

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

update(initialNodes);

function update(data) {
    // DATA JOIN
    // Join new data with old elements, if any.
    var circlesGroup = vis.selectAll("g.stop").data(data, function(d){return d.id});
    var circlesEnter = circlesGroup.enter().append("g").attr("class", "stop");
    var circlesExit  = circlesGroup.exit().remove();


    // ENTER
    // Create new elements as needed.
    circlesEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 15)
        .transition().duration(750)
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
          console.log('ENTERING: id:'+d.id+' position:'+d.x+','+d.y);
          return d.x;
          })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;})
        .style("fill", 'red');

    // UPDATE
    // Update old elements as needed.
    circlesGroup
        .transition().duration(750)
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
          console.log('ENTERING: id:'+d.id+' position:'+d.x+','+d.y);
          return d.x;})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;});

    // EXIT
    // Remove old elements as needed.
    circlesExit
        .remove();
}

var newNodes = [
                {"id": 0, "x": 50, "y": 100}, 
                {"id": 1, "x": 50, "y": 30},
                {"id": 2, "x": 100, "y": 50}
            ];

var updateNodes = function() {
    update(newNodes);
}

// Add the onclick callback to the button
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", updateNodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="updatebutton">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`circleGroup` is a selection of `g` elements. It has no purpose to set `cx` and `cy` for a `g` element.

After creating new nodes select all `g.stop` **and then** the containing circle. Why? Read the d3-selection doc.

There is no reason to add the second `remove()`.

```js
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

var initialNodes = [
    {"id": 0, "x": 50,  "y": 50},
    {"id": 1, "x": 100, "y": 100},
];

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

update(initialNodes);

function update(data) {
    // DATA JOIN
    // Join new data with old elements, if any.
    var circlesGroup = vis.selectAll("g.stop").data(data, function(d){return d.id});
    var circlesEnter = circlesGroup.enter().append("g").attr("class", "stop");
    var circlesExit  = circlesGroup.exit().remove();


    // ENTER
    // Create new elements as needed.
    circlesEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 15)
        .style("fill", 'red');
    vis.selectAll("g.stop").select("circle")
        .transition().duration(750)
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
          console.log('ENTERING2: id:'+d.id+' position:'+d.x+','+d.y);
          return d.x;})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;});
}

var newNodes = [
                {"id": 0, "x": 50, "y": 100}, 
                {"id": 1, "x": 50, "y": 30},
                {"id": 2, "x": 100, "y": 50}
            ];

var updateNodes = function() {
    update(newNodes);
}

// Add the onclick callback to the button
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", updateNodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="updatebutton">Update</button></div>
```